# How to create Array of matchcollection

Tags: c#, regex

I need help in minimizing the code. I have to check two different maches and need to store both in the same matchcollection. I dont know how to do, here is my code, can any one help me to do so please.

```
var patternEmail = @"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*";
MatchCollection emailCollection1;

 //Get emails from ResponsibleConsultant
emailCollection1 = Regex.Matches(piWorkitem.ResponsibleConsultant, patternEmail);
foreach (Match mail in emailCollection1.Cast<Match>().Where(mail => !emailaddresses.Contains(mail.Value.ToString())))
{
    emailaddresses.Add(mail.Value);
}

MatchCollection emailCollection2;

 //Get emails from ResponsibleConsultant
emailCollection2 = Regex.Matches(piWorkitem.SupplierConsultant, patternEmail);
foreach (Match mail in emailCollection2.Cast<Match>().Where(mail => !emailaddresses.Contains(mail.Value.ToString())))
{
    emailaddresses.Add(mail.Value);
}
```

Help me to do avoid the repeating the code more than once.

Comment: make a function containing the logic, then re-use the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var patternEmail = @"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*";
var allInput = piWorkitem.ResponsibleConsultant + " " + piWorkitem.SupplierConsultant;
var emailCollection = Regex.Matches(allInput , patternEmail);
foreach (Match mail in emailCollection.Cast<Match>().Where(mail => emailaddresses.Contains(mail.Value.ToString())))
{
    emailaddresses.Add(mail.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join both of the result using [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx)

Try this :

```
    var patternEmail = @"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*";

    var emailCollection1 = Regex.Matches(piWorkitem.ResponsibleConsultant, patternEmail).Cast<Match>().Union(Regex.Matches(piWorkitem.SupplierConsultant, patternEmail).Cast<Match>());
    foreach (Match mail in emailCollection1.Where(mail => !emailaddresses.Contains(mail.Value.ToString())))
    {
        emailaddresses.Add(mail.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void TestFunc()
    {
        var patternEmail = @"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*";

        var all = ExtactMatches(patternEmail, piWorkitem.SupplierConsultant, piWorkitem.ResponsibleConsultant);
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> ExtactMatches(string pattern, params string[] srcText)
    {
        HashSet<string> emailaddresses = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var text in srcText)
        {
            //Get emails from ResponsibleConsultant
            var emailCollection1 = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
            foreach (Match mail in emailCollection1.Cast<Match>().Where(mail => !emailaddresses.Contains(mail.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))))
            {
                emailaddresses.Add(mail.Value);
            }
        }
        return emailaddresses;
    }
```